# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Pulling from a csv file to populate an array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, scope

I am using the Leafleft Map API and a csv file to place markers on an interactive map (like an embedded google map) and I want to be able to click on a marker so that it changes the contents of a div tag (here with the id of infoName)on the website.

I get an error from the last line of code saying "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" and I think it has to do with promises and data fetching and maybe scope. 
Here is my code:

```
var restaurants = [];

makeMarkers();

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch('restaurantData.csv');
  const data = await response.text();

  const rows = data.split(/\n/).slice(1);
  rows.pop();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const col = rows[i].split(',');
    restaurants[i] = col;
  }
}

async function makeMarkers() {
  await getData();
  for (var j = 0; j < restaurants.length; j++) {
    L.marker([restaurants[j][7], restaurants[j][8]]).addTo(mymap).on('click', async function () {
            document.getElementById('infoName').textContent = await restaurants[j][0].toString();
          });
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: use /\r?\n/, and split on ',' isn't enough, because you need to account for quotes.  maybe consider using a csv library that has handled the edge cases for you.  also await doesn't make sense there, there's no Promise to wait on

Answer (score 0):

Probably a scoping issue.  `var` is hoisted, so restaurants[j] is actually using j after it has been incremented to restaurants.length.
Removed async because it is unnecessary there.

```
  for (var j = 0; j < restaurants.length; j++) {
    let k = j;
    L.marker([restaurants[k][7], restaurants[k][8]]).addTo(mymap).on('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('infoName').textContent = restaurants[k][0].toString();
          });
  }
```